# How to make an @AfterTest alwaysRun but only in the same group?

Tags: testng

I want my `@AfterTest` run even the test fails in the `@BeforeClass`. So I use the parameter `(alwaysRun = true)`.
But the problem is, the `@AfterTest` runs even in different group.
My test code is like this

In test1.kt:

```
@BeforeClass(groups = ["A"])
fun init() {...}

@Test(groups = ["A"])
fun test() {...}

@AfterTest(groups = ["A"], alwaysRun = true)
fun tesrdown() {...}
```

In test2.kt:

```
@BeforeClass(groups = ["B"])
fun init() {...}

@Test(groups = ["B"])
fun test() {...}

@AfterTest(groups = ["B"], alwaysRun = true)
fun tesrdown() {...}
```

Now if I only run test with `group == ["B"]`, the `@AfterTest` for group A will still be executed.
Is there a way that make `@AfterTest` only runs while `groups == ["A"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`alwaysRun = true` makes sure that the method gets executed every time, and that's why `@AfterTest` of group = "A" getting executed when you executed group= "B".

You can remove `@alwaysRun` option from both `@AfterTest` and keep only `groups = "B"` or `groups= "A"`

When you include any group for execution in a test run only `@AfterTest` of that group will be executed.